# Clutter-gst-3.0-3.0.24-r0 oe_runmake and do_compile failed when building Yocto

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, yocto, bitbake, clutter

I am attempting to build a Yocto Toolchain as per the documentation found [here](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Build_Release&release=RELEASE_SUMO_V2.5_DART-MX8M-MINI) and [here.](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Toolchain_installation&release=RELEASE_SUMO_V2.5_DART-MX8M-MINI)

Attempting to run the bitbake command, the following issues spring up:

```
Makefile:813: recipe for target 'clutter-gst-plugin.lo' failed 
make[4]: *** [clutter-gst-plugin.lo] Error 1 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/carter/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/clutter-gst-3.0/3.0.24-r0/build/clutter-gst' 
ERROR: oe_runmake failed 
Makefile:912: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed 
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/carter/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/clutter-gst-3.0/3.0.24-r0/build/clutter-gst' 
Makefile:655: recipe for target 'all' failed make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/carter/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/clutter-gst-3.0/3.0.24-r0/build/clutter-gst' 
Makefile:534: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed 
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/carter/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/clutter-gst-3.0/3.0.24-r0/build' 
Makefile:442: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2 
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

I have tried to reinstall all dependencies, restarted building, etc, but nothing so far has worked in terms of solving this issue. Currently, as per the guide has outlined, I am running this through an Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine on Oracle VirtualBox, although I do not believe the virtual machine to be causing this issue. I'm quite stumped on what I should try next.

When I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` it did actually cause the bitbake to last longer, but it still caused an error eventually. This is in addition to attempting to install many other packages from various other sites of documentation.